# Getting Forms on Page in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a web vulnerability scanner. I have completed 30% of the program, in that it can scan only HTTP GET methods. But I've hit a snag now: I have no idea how I shall make the program pentest the POST method.

I had the idea to make it extract the form data/names from all the pages on the website, but I have no idea how I should do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for screen scraping.

For heavier scripting, use [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) :

> twill is a simple language that allows users to browse the Web from a command-line interface. With twill, you can navigate through Web sites that use forms, cookies, and most standard Web features.

With twill, you can easily fill forms and `POST` them back to a server. Twill has a [Python API](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html). A from-filling  example:

```
from twill.commands import go, showforms, formclear, fv, submit

go('http://issola.caltech.edu/~t/qwsgi/qwsgi-demo.cgi/')
go('./widgets')
showforms()

formclear('1')
fv("1", "name", "test")
fv("1", "password", "testpass")
fv("1", "confirm", "yes")
showforms()

submit('0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to use [urllib2](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-urllib2.html) to execute a POST method?

You might want to look at the [examples](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/urllib2-examples.html).

After trying some of that, you might want to post code with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to collect the data/names from the form, you just need a way to deal with http POST method. I guess you will need a solution for sending multipart form-data.

You should look at the MultipartPostHandler:

http://odin.himinbi.org/MultipartPostHandler.py

And if you need to support unicode file names , see a fix at:
http://peerit.blogspot.com/2007/07/multipartposthandler-doesnt-work-for.html